# Outlook Email - Filter Creation

Tags: email, outlook, gmail

This is more of a product related question to increase productivity.

In outlook express, Is there a way to filter emails by senders who have sent only one email? Whether there is filter rule.

It would be awesome if we have that rule in Gmail as well.

Thanks!